# My System.IO.File.WriteAllText coding doesn't create a file after it has once been deleted in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, .net

**CONCLUSION AT BOTTOM OF POST**

I'm a novice with C# and have only just begun using System.IO, but haven't been able to find information on my issue so wanted to ask the guys here:

I have a program that when run, creates a directory, then writes to a .txt file what the most recent value of a certain variable was, so that if the program is interrupted or the computer loses power, restarting the program will retrieve that stored number from the .txt file.

I've simply done this:

```
    string INSTATR = LastValue.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\DotTempFiles\\"+Instrument.Name+"ATR.txt", INSTATR);
```

My first time running this program, the file was created, and I found that on every cycle the number in the file was being overwritten to the last valid number just as I wanted.

However, once I went to the DotTempFiles directory and deleted the .txt file using Shift+Del, the file has never returned upon running the program as I thought it would.  If I delete the entire directory and run the program, the directory is recreated but still not the file.

If I run the program using a different Instrument.Name, that new file is created as expected, but the original one that I once manually deleted is still not showing, even after computer restarts.

I can't find any information leads online, so does anyone have an idea?  Thank you!

**EDIT (more info):**  People asked a few questions so I'm adding more information (thank you)

There are no errors being reported.  It compiles fine, and when running, there is an output window that usually alerts me to errors like if I reference an object that is null, or try to read from an empty file, etc.  No errors like this are occurring.

More background on what the program is.  There is a stock trading program called NinjaTrader that has their own API based on C#.  They wouldn't support the questions I have because it's outside the normal scope of the script development they intended people to use, and that's ok with me.  The program itself is a trading strategy that is run within NinjaTrader, and it exposes default programmer access to these two main methods:

Initialize()

protected override void OnBarUpdate()  //this is the main part of the program that gets called every time a change has occurred to one of the bars on the stock chart.

In the variable declaration section I have this:

```
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\DotTempFiles");
```

And in OnStartUp() I have this:

```
    //Set up ReadMe file in the temp directory in case people wonder why it keeps appearing
    string README = "This DotTempFiles directory is created by the strategy every time it is run, and temporary text files with the name [instrumentsymbol]ATR.txt are written into it containing the last highest ATRStopValue for the strategy, which if it is stopped and restarted with an open position, it will read from that file to get back the best value instead of recalculating it with possibility of a lower unwanted value.";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\DotTempFiles\\README.txt", README);
```

Every time OnBarUpdate() is called, which can be up to a few times per second, it first calculates a double called LastValue which is a number related to the stock price, then it converts it to a string INSTATR, then writes it to a .txt file.

```
    string INSTATR = LastValue.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\DotTempFiles\\"+Instrument.Name+"ATR.txt", INSTATR);
```

And this is every single piece of code I have connected to this issue.  As I mentioned above, it created the file the first time, but since I've deleted the file in windows explorer, it isn't able to recreate it.  However, deleting the directory and restarting the strategy program does recreate that directory.

OnTermination() is not being used to close or delete the file in any way (just in case people wanted to ask) -- I am not using any other code to interact with the file than the ones already shown.  Thanks!

**EDIT 2 (Update after reading comments):**  Thank you guys for your comments and help.  What I'll do when I get back to my home is try recreating the minimal version of this with an empty program containing just these lines of code and see what the outcome is, and I'll post updates in either way.

**EDIT 3**:  Thank you Steve, that is a very good idea that I should use from now on for these kinds of things.

**EDIT 4 (Conclusion):**  Well, I found out that I overlooked something simple about my own code logic.  I was setting the File.WriteAllText to trigger any time the Double variable increased in value, not on every call of the OnBarUpdate method.  Because of this, the file would not be written except once every few hours or so and now I see that everything is working properly.  I am sorry that I made all these people read this post since it was based on another issue of my own fault.  However, I am very thankful to everyone for their comments that helped me get to this point, and to Steve and Mark Lakata for their tips that I learned some new good things from.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error? Have you tried writing a minimal reproduction of the error? For instance just the above two lines in a new C# program.

Comment: You haven't posted enough of your code for us to help you with this. Please post **all** of your relevant code.

Comment: There must be something else wrong with your program because `File.WriteAllText` works as expected when you `SHIFT`+`DEL` a file.

Comment: While not a solution for your problem, I would recommend using a different place to store your file. Use something like `System.Environment.GetFolder(System.Environment.SpecialFolders.AppData)`, and create a directory under that with the same name as your program.

Comment: Your file name is a bit wonky, since you are misusing the `@""` construct. Either use `@"C:\DotTempFiles\ATR.txt"` or `"C:\\DotTempFiles\\ATR.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there is nothing wrong with the file creation, it was the fact that my coding logic was just calling for it far less frequently than I assumed it was (once every few hours vs several times per second)